# getting a particular value in pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a data frame named `df`

```
       season   seed    team
1609    2010    W01     1246
1610    2010    W02     1452
1611    2010    W03     1307
1612    2010    W04     1458
1613    2010    W05     1396
```

I need to a new data frame in the following format:

```
team  frequency
1246    01 
1452    02 
1307    03
1458    04
1396    05
```

The frequency value came by taking the value from the column named `seed` in data frame `df`

```
W01 -> 01
W02 -> 02
W03 -> 03
```

How do I do this in pandas?

Comment: Is it always a W?  Or is it sometimes an L?  Guessing your trying to make some March Madness money.

Comment: @LiamFoley Yes exactly I am solving that problem. how did you know that?

Comment: What does seed represent?  That is, how do you go from W02 to 2? Or do you actually want 02?

Comment: W02 is the column value(seed) in my data frame in df. I need to exclude the W value in my seed column and get only the numerical values(01, 02)

Comment: @MJP B/C I'm a basketball fan too... Go Cats (UA)!

Comment: @LiamFoley Great! why dont you help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution below uses a lambda function to apply a regex to remove non-digit characters.

http://pythex.org/?regex=%5CD&test_string=L16a&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0

```
import pandas as pd
import re

index=[1609,1610,1611,1612,1613,1700]
data = {'season':[2010,2010,2010,2010,2010,2010],
        'seed':['W01','W02','W03','W04','W05','L16a'],
        'team':[1246,1452,1307,1458,1396,0000]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data,index=index)

df['frequency'] = df['seed'].apply(lambda x: int(re.sub('\D', '', x)))
df2 = df[['team','frequency']].set_index('team')
```

Comment: Solution is great. but when I apply this to my original data frame I am getting an error "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '16a'"

Comment: @MJP Edited to use the regex library to keep only digits.  Should work now.  Didn't like try to transform 'a' into an integer before.

Comment: If you dont mind can you explain what exactly does `int(re.sub('\D', '', x)` I am not that familiar with regex.

Comment: It is taking everything that matches a specific pattern and replacing it with an empty string (''), then it turns the remaining string of digits into an integer.  http://pythex.org/?regex=%5CD&test_string=L16a&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0

Answer (score 1):

```
# Setup your DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'season': [2010]*5, 'seed': ['W0' + str(i) for i in range(1,6)], 'team': [1246, 1452, 1307, 1458, 1396]}, index=range(1609, 1614))
s = pd.Series(df['seed'].str[1:].values, index=df['team'], name='frequency')
print(s)
```

yields

```
team
1246    01
1452    02
1307    03
1458    04
1396    05
Name: frequency, dtype: object
```

Comment: I am getting an error "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '16a'".   I tried to convert a column frequency as df['frequency'].astype(int) again the same error occurs.  What should I do to convert the string values in frequency columns to integers?